# How to update GeometryReader values with onRecieve [SwiftUI, macos]

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a task list that renders rows of text. I've implemented drag n' drop so that rows can be reodered. I'm using GeometryReader to keep track of the Text frames, so I know where I'm dropping things and how to reorder.

The issue is after I've reordered once, I can't reorder again correctly, because the frames are not updated.

Seems like "geo" from GeometryReader, doesn't get updated every time the Text field moves. It's only updated the first time.

```swift
Text("Hello world")
  .overlay(
    GeometryReader { geo in
    Color.clear
      .onReceive(self.didSave) { _ in
        // Problem: geo never updates, even if Text has moved.
        self.textFrame[index] = geo.frame(in: .global)
      }
    }
  )
```

Is there a way to have "geo" update as the item it's overlayed on moved?

**Edit:

So I ended up fixing this another way. The update works fine onAppear of Geometry reader. So in onRecieve, I set a boolean named refreshGeometryReader, to render the Text without the overlay and then do:

```
if(refreshGeometryReader) {
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    self.refreshGeometryReader = false
  }
}
```

This forces the overlay to disappear and reappear after 0.1 seconds, and thus geo is updated because it's a new instance of GeometryReader all together.

This is hacky, but works well enough for my needs. Hopefully someone finds a better way to get GeometryReader to update anytime it's parent moves. Maybe using `.position` as @asperi suggested will work for someone else. Didn't make sense for my specific use case.

Comment: How do you move Text? If you do this with `.offset` then layout is not changed, and that's might be reason. It needs to be moved with `.position`.

Comment: @Asperi Ah ok. I am using `.offset`. will try with `.position` and report back.

Comment: I have the same problem.. I move the items with `.position`